# Tips for finding equilibria of high-dimensional nonlinear dynamical systems

Tags: dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes, stability-theory, fixed-points

In order to perform stability analysis, I seek to find fixed points in a couple of relatively high-dimension (10-30 state variables) nonlinear dynamical systems composed of ordinary time-derivatives. For the curious these are computational models of neurons.

Whilst i was able to find such points for my lowest dimension model (Dim=10), I'm struggling to do so for any other model.

Would welcome any tips regarding techniques to facilitate search or tools I could use to symbolically or numerically solve the more complex models. At the moment I'm using matlab's symbolic math toolbox.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried with another tools like SAGE or Mathematica?

Comment: Thanks, I'll try SAGE, I've only tried other python libraries like sympy (which are magnitudes slower than matlab). And will try to get a license to give mathematica a shot.